# Megamenu Top of header position in OpenCart 2

Tags: position, opencart2.x, megamenu

I currently have megamenu module active and working on my website(OpenCart 2.0). There is many position available but not like I need. The position I need is top of logo/header. By meaning that Megamenu is first thing were website starts. But I dont need sticky megamenu.

Comment: share some screenshots or provide a link so we can understand exact problem.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/ryl3ah9uf/ Link for screenshot. Best Regards. So that position Header Top is missing from Megamenu position options.